# How to control preventDefault?

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I'd like to use `preventDefault` on a parent element, but I don't want it to effect the child elements. Can this be done?

*I've setup a JsFiddle to help show what I mean*:
http://jsfiddle.net/StephenMeehan/FdwST/5/

I've been scratching my head over this for a few hours, can't figure it out...

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="SidebarNav">
<li><a href="#">Toys &amp; Games</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Audio Visual</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">Furniture (Hover over this)</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">Menu item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Gadgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">Furniture (Hover over this)</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">Menu item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// This is my first attempt at writing something useful in jQuery.
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#SidebarNav ul").hide();

    $("li:has(ul)").addClass("SubMenu");


    // preventDefault removes default events on #SidebarNav a and it's children. 
    //Is there a way to only target list items with a class of .SubMenu?
    // I want to use preventDefault only on .SubMenu a, and still be able to use the links in the drop down menu.
    $(".SubMenu a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    // This works, but it sometimes gets confused if there's more than one drop down and the mouse is moved around too fast. Is there a way to force collapse all other SubMenu items on rollover?
    $(".SubMenu").on("hover", function() {
        $(this).children("ul").delay(100).slideToggle("fast").stop();
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After what I can understand, all you need is to add a `:first` to the `.SubMenu a` selector to just pick the first `a` to prevent the default behavior on.

So use: `$(".SubMenu a:first").click ....`

Check out the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) on the `:first`selector

Edit: [A JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FdwST/6/) for you

Comment: Just tried this - it works if there is only one instance of .SubMenu unfortunately it doesn't work if there are more than one. Any ideas?

Comment: After a bit more head scratching I was able to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

`>` allows you to select direct children of an element, playing with these should work.

So in your case how about :

```
$(".SubMenu > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

For more info on jquery direct descendant selector see: [api.jquery.com/child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector)

Comment: It will not do it on anything, because it's the `li` that has the `SubMenu` class.

Comment: This works, although it shouldn't? hmmmm .SubMenu > a should only target children of .SubMenu - I'll continue to tinker with this tomorrow. I'll post any updates here.

Comment: @StephenMeehan `$(".SubMenu > a")` target only directly descending `a` tags. So the one contains in the `li` tags wont be targeted. See this http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ThoKra for answering the question. I got this to work in the end. This will find all the first a tags within all the classes of .SubMenu.

```
$(".SubMenu").find("a:first").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

JQuery below will only find the first a tag in the first instance of .SubMenu, my page had multiple instance of .SubMenu, so it wasn't quite right.

```
$(".SubMenu a:first").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

*Hope this helps anyone looking for a similar solution. Thanks again ThoKra.*